# Android studio layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Всем доброго времени суток.

Создается приложение типа справочника. Имеется экран, в нем кнопки с названием тем и при открытии их в них тест с картинками возник следующий вопрос: как правильней делать экран для этих тем, то есть для каждой темы свой "layout.xml"? или можно как то текст всех тем передавать в один "layout" и работать тока с одним "layout"? или есть еще какой то способ?

Comment: Ответ на Ваш вопрос зависит от структуры этих самых тем. В общем случае, если они все разные, то придется для каждой темы создавать свой layout.

Comment: То есть можно так же можно передать одну картинки для ScrollingActivity на каждую тему?

Comment: Не понял вопроса.

Comment: Ну структура шаблона у ScrollingActivity есть картинка сверху потом идет текст. И я имею ввиду для каждой темы можно менять эту картинку в одном layout.

Comment: Если структура шаблона разметки и логика взаимодействия с пользователем в активити для всех тестов одинаковая, то в активити с тестом достаточно передавать только данные, которые потом программно устанавливаются в виджеты одной и той же разметки. Чтобы получить полезный ответ, вопрос должен содержать больше технических деталей, относящиеся к вопросу (какие данные, где хранятся, как должно взаимодействовать и тд) и меньше "воды". Так же код того, что было сделано и что не получается и тд. Как задавать вопросы, [чтобы получить полезный ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ!